# : nth child selector class is not applied on my page I would like to apply on second

Tags: css

```
<ul class="nav">
<li class="dropdown opener"><a href="https://moodle.org" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Moodle community">Moodle community</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropotron level-0 left">
<li><a title="Moodle free support" href="https://moodle.org/support">Moodle free support</a></li>
<li class="divider">&nbsp;</li>
<li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="https://moodle.org/development" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Moodle development">Moodl</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropotron level-0 left">
<li><a title="Moodle Docs" href="http://docs.moodle.org">Moodle Docs</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="divider">&nbsp;</li>
<li><a title="Moodle.com" href="http://moodle.com/">Moodle.com</a></li>
<li class="dropdown opener langmenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Language">English (en)</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropotron level-0 left">
<li><a title="English (en)" href="http://192.168.1.123/moodle30nw/?redirect=0&amp;lang=en">English (en)</a></li>
<li><a title="عربي (ar)" href="http://192.168.1.123/moodle30nw/?redirect=0&amp;lang=ar">عربي (ar)</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
.navbar .nav > li:nth-of-type(2) a:hover{
    background-color: #407a61 !important; 
    color:#fff !important;
 }
```

Why my css is not working here i would like to change the hover background-color of the second element how can i apply it. Is any other way to do it.

Comment: Could you please post [mcve] including HTML?

Comment: I hope you have a an element with class 'navbar' as i don't see it here in the html code you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Check Here Your [Answer](https://jsfiddle.net/pxoLLshp/3/)

You have to remove `>` operator from the CSS
Here is the [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pxoLLshp/)

HTML

```
<div class="navbar ">
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
    <li>First One</li>
    <li>Second One</li>
    <li>Three One</li>
    <li>Four One</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar .nav  li:nth-of-type(2):hover {

    color:red;
 }
```

Comment: I want to add background color on a tag hover

Comment: @user3282537   Please Check Now

Comment: @user3282537 I hope you have a an element with class 'navbar' as i don't see it here in the html code you provided